# How can I combine logical vectors?

Tags: r, concatenation

Good morning,

I am coding in R.
I have three logical vectors :

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6
a T T F F T F
b F T F F F F
c F F F T F F
```

And I would like to obtain a vector telling me if a position is set to true in at least one of the three vector :

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6
a T T F T T F
```

I have tried to used :

```
Reduce("&&",a,b,c)
```

But it didn't work.

Thank you if you have any idea or advice to solve my problem,

Comment: "true in at least one place" means "TRUE in a OR b OR c"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `|` in this case

```
a|b|c
```

If there are multiple vectors, place it in a `list` and use `Reduce` with `|`

```
Reduce(`|`, list(a, b, c))
```

#### data

```
a <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)
b <- c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
c <- c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)
```

Comment: Or less efficiently but maybe more readable for some `mapply(any, a, b, c)`

Answer (score 2):

since your data is in a matrix format, you can do:

```
colSums(dat)>0
    1     2     3     4     5     6 
 TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

data:

```
dat=read.table(text="  1 2 3 4 5 6
a T T F F T F
b F T F F F F
c F F F T F F",strip=T,h=T)
names(dat)=1:6
```

Answer (score 1):

May be this can do as well:

```
Reduce(`+`,list(a,b,c)) > 0
```

or more simply could be:

```
a+b+c > 0
```

Where Input can be:

```
a <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)
b <- c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
c <- c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)
```

**Output**:

```
> Reduce(`+`,list(a,b,c)) > 0
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```